# How to ensure unique vertex and edge in orientdb 3.0?

Tags: java, orientdb, graph-databases

I am using [OVertex](http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/java/ref/OVertex.html) and [OEdge](http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/java/ref/OEdge.html) to store data points. My data points may be repetitive and non unique, how to I ensure that orientdb stores them unique (based on a certain property). I can't seem to find anything in the documentation that helps. I am using orientdb 3.0. I am looking for a way to do this with the Java multi model API.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a UNIQUE index on a property:

```
CREATE INDEX Person.uuid on Person(uuid) UNIQUE
```

The full documentation about indexes is here: http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/sql/SQL-Create-Index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation. I was looking for a JAVA API way to do this, that is why I linked classes from there. I found a way and did post my answer, apologies for the delay

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the JAVA multi model API the cleanest way I found was:

```
 // create the connection pool for orientdb
OrientDB orient = new OrientDB(orientUrl, OrientDBConfig.defaultConfig());
OrientDBConfigBuilder poolCfg = OrientDBConfig.builder();
poolCfg.addConfig(OGlobalConfiguration.DB_POOL_MIN, 2);
poolCfg.addConfig(OGlobalConfiguration.DB_POOL_MAX, 5);
ODatabasePool pool = new ODatabasePool(orientUrl, databaseName, orientUser, orientPass, poolCfg.build());

// acquire the orient pool connection
try (ODatabaseSession db = pool.acquire()) {
        // check and create vertex/edge class
        if (db.getClass("className") == null) {
            // create the class if it does not exist in the DB
            OClass orientClass =
                    db.createVertexClass("className");
            // OR db.createEdgeClass("className");
            orientClass.createProperty("id", OType.STRING);
            orientClass.createIndex("id", OClass.INDEX_TYPE.UNIQUE, "id");
        }
       // now create the OVertex/OEdge/OElement
       OVertex vertex = db.newVertex("className");
       // add properties to your document
       vertex.setProperty("id", id);
       ...
// release the connection back to the pool
} finally {
        orient.close();
    }
```

I did not find this in the documention yet, so maybe it helps someone.